# Controlling volume of Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, avplayer, watchos, watchos-6

I'm trying to control the volume of the Apple Watch itself in code from SwiftUI.

I'm streaming audio using the `AVPlayer`.

Is there an API to set the Volume of the Watch or use to Digital Crown to control the volume without

- Setting the `volume` property on the `AVPlayer`. This just set the volume relative to the system volume. So if the system is muted it does not increase the volume.
- Using the `WKInterfaceVolumeControl`. This does the job, but it can not be sized does and takes a lot of space on the small screen.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: I ended up adding a `WKInterfaceVolumeControl` through `WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable` to the View hierarchy and settings its `opacity` to `0`. You have to make sure that the volume control keeps the focus. I added a repeating timer where I set the focus, just to be sure. 
Then then observe `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().observe(\.outputVolume)` and update a smaller view in code.
This works ok... On my older watch there is quite a lack between the volume changing and the app getting the volume update. But I think it is the only way to control the volume without the big control.

Comment: hi @leoMehlig Could you please share more details and example with little code as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The workaround I ended up with was this:

1. Wrap the `WKInterfaceVolumeControl` to use it in SwiftUI

```
struct VolumeView: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {
    typealias WKInterfaceObjectType = WKInterfaceVolumeControl


    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: Self.Context) -> WKInterfaceVolumeControl {
        let view = WKInterfaceVolumeControl(origin: .local)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak view] timer in
            if let view = view {
                view.focus()
            } else {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.focus()
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ wkInterfaceObject: WKInterfaceVolumeControl, context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<VolumeView>) {
    }
}
```

2. Add the `VolumeView` to the view hierarchy with `opacity = 0`.

```
        .background(VolumeView().opacity(0))
```

3. Listen to volume updates from the system.

```
volumeObserver = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().observe(\.outputVolume) { session, _ in
            print("Output volume: \(session.outputVolume)")
            self.volume = Double(session.outputVolume)
        }
```

With that you can update some other view, but keep in mind that especially on older what's the update does not always happen (immediately).

Comment: This gave me the right direction, thanks!
For me it worked, the insert a WKInterfaceVolumeControl into my 'Player' Interface Controller and set its 'Alpha' to '0'. Currently I didn't found 'focus' problems.

Answer (score 1):

[leoMehlig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282442/3151675) only works for me if I add a bit of delay and resign the focus before focusing for the first time.

So, speaking in code, I changed this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    view.focus()
}
```

to this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
    view.resignFocus()
    view.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[leoMehlig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282442/10942511) **works for me as is**, but I noticed the embedded WKInterfaceVolumeControl was losing focus when I would tap anywhere on the watch screen.

This was because I had a `.focusable(true)` modifier in the view hierarchy, so any view being tapped further up in the hierarchy would keep the focus.

I had added the `.focusable(true)` when I was trying to bind `AVPlayer.volume` to the digital crown rotation, it was no longer needed when using `WKInterfaceVolumeControl`